# Does $\lim_{e \rightarrow 0}$ $ \int^{+e}_{-e} f(x) dx \rightarrow 0$ for all finite $f(x)$?

Tags: calculus

Does $\lim_{e \rightarrow 0}$ $ \int^{+e}_{-e} f(x) dx \rightarrow 0$ for all finite $f(x)$? And, if so, why? [This comes up when showing that Schrodinger's Equation is continuous](https://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node141.html).

Comment: Finite doesn't imply integrable.  You need to make that assumption.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Finite $f$ can be unbounded on every neighbourhood.  Take a discontinuous solution to Cauchy functional equation, for example.

Comment: Sure, I take it back. I automatically assumed 'finite' meant 'bounded'. Its not so usual to see "finite" attached to a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Note that if $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[-\varepsilon,\varepsilon]$, then in particular $f$ is bounded on this interval, and we have the inequality:
$$\left|\int_{-\varepsilon}^\varepsilon f(x)\,dx\right|\leq\sup_{|x|\leq\varepsilon}|f(x)|\int_{-\varepsilon}^\varepsilon\,dx=\sup_{|x|\leq\varepsilon}|f(x)|\cdot2\varepsilon.$$
As $\varepsilon\to0$, the rightmost quantity vanishes, and so the desired result follows from the squeeze theorem.